# Pear dependencies in Ant

Tags: php, ant, pear

What's a good way to include Pear dependencies in ant/ivy. Should I use phing or is there a  better way using ant?

Thanks,
Sriranjan

Answer (score 0):

Dependency tracking for PEAR packages is ideally made with .. pear and a meta package: http://pear.php.net/manual/en/guide.users.dependencytracking.php